# Every view without the Navbar or Tabbar is pushed down 20px

Tags: xcode, ios, interface, interface-builder, nib

I'm building my iphone app.

I've got a problem. For every view without the Navigation bar and the Tab bar is pulled up of 20px.

So I have to place every elements 20px below the top edge.
In this screenshot http://ge.tt/4FG1fJ9 you see the Interface builder view, with 20px bar space at the top, and the result into the Simulator.
This solution works, but give me some problems, and it's not elegant.

I'm wondering why all this happens.
Have you got any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder, open your xib, click on the root UIView and then hit Cmd-1. That will bring you to the UIView Attributes window. There are a few drop downs for "Simulated UI Elements" and you can set the Status Bar to Black (or whatever the option is). This doesn't *add* the status bar to your view, it just simulates the size of the status bar so that you can layout your views without having to shift everything down by 20 pixels.

Comment: There's yet the status bar. It's added as default... Thanks for the help, but this hasn't solved the problem

Comment: What are the dimensions of your top-level UIView? More importantly... how are you adding this view to your existing view? Can you show us the code that displays this view?

Comment: This is the code.      nextController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];        
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:nextController.view];

Comment: Ah, that sounds like the problem. Instead of the addSubview call, you want to present/push a new view controller. If you want to stay in the same navigation controller, you can do: [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES]; If you want the new view controller to take up the entire screen, try [self presentModalViewController:nextController animated:YES];

Comment: And to remove a presentModalViewController?

Comment: Inside either the view controller that did the presenting or the view controller that is the modal, call -dismissingModalViewController:animted;

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem that seems to rear it's head in different ways. The cause, though, usually has to do with poor coordination of the status bar.

I was able to reproduce the problem just now in a test app by adding a 'Status bar is initially hidden' line to my Info.plist and setting it to YES. The app looks fine in the main view, but if I push a new view controller and then set the status bar to display, the new view appears shifted down 20px. That is, the top of the view appears 20px below the bottom of the status bar.

I know that's not a terribly specific answer, but take a look at how you're hiding/showing the status bar in your app, and also how you have the simulated status bar in your .xib files set.